# select year 2014 from an object

Tags: filtering

could you help me to filter the year 2014 from the following object:

```
 data={{2013.09.17, 60.},{2013.10.07, 100.}, ...... }
```

Basically I just want to select one year from this object, but I'm struggling with the select statement.

My idea: `Select[data,#[[1]]==DateObject[{2014}]]`

Comment: Try `Select[data,DateValue[DateObject[#[[1]]], "Year"]==2014]`  (assuming whats actually in the input are just strings like "2013.09.17" )

Comment: Thanks :) Select[data,DateValue[DateObject[#[[1]]], "Year"]==2014&] works